# Collect user inputs and then print those to screen in a formatted string

Tags: python

I collect 3 inputs from the user, two numbers `a` and `b`, and a mathematical operator `sign`. My code is as follows:

```py
a = int(input('Type the number: '))
b = int(input('Type the number: '))
sign = input('Type a sign as + etc : ')
print(a sign b)
```

I have to use these inputs to print to screen `2 + 5`, if the inputs were `a = 2`, `b = 5`, `sign = '+'`.

How would I go about evaluating these inputs to output `7`?

Comment: Read topics related f string  will help to get your output

Comment: You want to print the actual result or just the literal equation?

Comment: if you want the result of the equation, try `eval(str(a) + sign + str(b))`. If you don't want to use `eval` then you might have to write a mini-parser yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use a sequence of `if`s, or you could use a dictionary that looks up the operator in the `operator` builtin (this contains standard operators as callable functions): https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html

For example,

```
import operator
operators = {'<': operator.le, '+': operator.add, ...}
print(operators[sign](a, b))
```

Answer (score 1):

Although I'm not really sure what the question is asking,

You can use plus signs to concatenate strings

```
a = int(input('Type the number: ')) 
b = int(input('Type the number: ')) 
sign = input('Type a sign as + etc : ') 
print(str(a) + sign + str(b))
```

You can *also* add commas to place spaces between the strings.

```
a = int(input('Type the number: ')) 
b = int(input('Type the number: ')) 
sign = input('Type a sign as + etc : ') 
print(str(a), sign, str(b))
```

Or using [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals)

```
a = int(input('Type the number: ')) 
b = int(input('Type the number: ')) 
sign = input('Type a sign as + etc : ') 
print(f"{str(a)} {sign} {str(b)}")
```

Answer (score 0):

print function can't show int and string at the same time.

This will do the trick

```
a = int(input('Type the number: '))
b = int(input('Type the number: '))
sign = input('Type a sign as + etc : ')
print(f'{a} {sign} {b}')  # f string
```

[f string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) is newer syntax for formatting.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = int(input('Type the number: '))
b = int(input('Type the number: '))
sign = input('Type a sign as + etc : ')

if sign == "+": print(a + b)
elif sign == "-": print(a - b)
elif sign == "/": print(a / b)
elif sign == "*": print(a * b)
else: print("I can't understand it :(")
```

Answer (score 0):

You should define a function. I guess it should do the trick.
`a = int(input("Type the number: ")) b = int(input("Type another number: ")) c = input("Please enter a sign as + etc: ")`

```
    def sign(x, y):
        if c == "+":
            return x + y
        elif c == "-":
            return x - y
        elif c == "*":
            return x * y
        elif c == "/":
            return x // y


    print(sign(a, b))
```